# Why is the GPU not rendering normal map correctly?

Tags: rendering, uv, gpu

I'm encountering this strange problem where if I render out my image in Cycles with a gpu the normal map is messed up. Perhaps inverted.

It renders fine with the cpu (top image is rendered with CPU, bottom with GPU)

[image: CPU]
[image: GPU]

Machine: Predator G9-591
CPU: i7-6700HQ
GPU: GeForce GTX 970m
OS: Windows 10
Version:Blender 2.77a

screenshot of the jean material node.
[image]

Comment: You mean on the pants' pocket, right?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your nodes for that material/texture?

Comment: I wanna say this is a bug...?

Comment: @someonewithpc a bug it can be (as is it just a rendering way difference), but hard to now if the pocket model (mesh, normals) cannot be checked....

Comment: How many 16/32bit textures do you have? If you have more than 5 and your normal map is one of them, it won't load as Cycles in 2.77 is limited to 5 "float" textures (which is anything not 8bit). This is not the case in the nightly builds on buildbot, if you want to try that.

Comment: Yea, I believe it is just a problem on the jeans. add a screenshot of the node.

Answer (score 0):

Normal maps or other data maps' color space should be as Non-Color
also, I recommend turning off the Half-float Precision option for Normal maps.
[image]